# Постановка запятой перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация, как

Прошу, объясните все случаи постановки и отсутствия запятой перед "***как***".

Допустим, на примере этого предложения:

***Никого не заботят проблемы другого, как свои.***

Мне думается, что запятая тут требуется из-за наличия эллипса: ***никого не заботят проблемы другого (так), как свои.***

Comment: "Все случаи" вряд ли возможно охватить. Советую просмотреть вопросы и ответы с меткой "как".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Никого не заботят проблемы другого, как свои.**

Для начала определим семантику оборота. Здесь он имеет значение **сопоставления** (другой - свой), которое близко к значению сравнения. Оборот соответствует  придаточному предложению: **Никого не заботят проблемы другого так, как заботят свои проблемы.**  Соответственно, такой оборот обособляется.

Но этот же оборот может являться **необособленным обстоятельством** и иметь значение "**в качестве своих**".  В этом случае на оборот падает логическое ударение, пауза отсутствует.

В некоторых случаях, когда структура предложения такова, что возможны оба варианта прочтения,  обособление оборота является  **авторским решением**.

Сравним эти варианты на примерах:

**1) Обособляется со значением сопоставления** (ударением выделены сопоставляемые слова)

И Куренкова передернуло от того, что Шурочка прочла **егО мысли, как своИ**.

И **норвЕжские газеты** можно читать почти так же свободно, **как своИ,** датские.

**ЕЁ удачи** радовали нас, **как свои**.

**2) Нет обособления, значение "в качестве"**

Через весь фильм зритель страдает вместе с героями, осознавая их ошибки **как свои.**  Здесь возможно обособление, авторский выбор.

Он принял дороги войны **как свои**, хотя был моложе фронтовиков.

Кстати, переживать несчастье и беды близких **как свои** ― это, по Декарту,  высший вид привязанности и любви.

Неверно пишут некоторые «биографы» о Вертинском, что он использовал чужие стихи **как свои.**